# Symbolic Evaluation of Convolve Between DiracDeltas Where the Variable Appears In a Sqrt

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

[This notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jabowery/Published/SpherePlaneConvolveFail.nb)'s `Convolve` won't symbolically evaluate this one dimensional convolution in tau:

```
Convolve[DiracDelta[Sqrt[1+tau^2]],DiracDelta[tau],tau,z]
```

Is this because the variable `tau` appears inside `Sqrt`?  If so, how can one get Mathematica to perform this symbolic convolution?

Comment: As far as I know the product of DiracDeltas isn't defined.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't argee.  Mathematica evaluates the following simpler function `Convolve[DiracDelta[tau - r0], DiracDelta[tau], tau, z]`

Comment: I didn't know how to make `DiracDelta` plural in a title such that it wouldn't be confused with me asserting there was such a thing as Wolfram language function `DiracDeltas`.

Comment: @mikado Thanks for your comment. You're right, via Fouriertransform the convolution is defined!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To evaluate the convolution you need the transformation rule

[image]

( see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) )

```
xi = Solve[Sqrt[rho^2 + tau^2] - r0 == 0, tau]
gsi = D[Sqrt[rho^2 + tau^2] - r0, tau] /. xi
res = (Flatten[xi] /. Rule -> Subtract)
dirac = Total@MapThread[DiracDelta[#1]/ Abs[#2] &, {res, gsi}]
```

convolution

```
Convolve[dirac, DiracDelta[tau], tau, z]
(*DiracDelta[Sqrt[r0^2 - rho^2] - z]/Abs[Sqrt[r0^2 - rho^2]/Sqrt[r0^2]] + 
DiracDelta[Sqrt[r0^2 - rho^2] + z]/Abs[Sqrt[r0^2 - rho^2]/Sqrt[r0^2]] *)
```

Comment: You should add a caveat to your answer that it doesn't work in the case of multiple dimensions.  This caveat is needed because the example given uses a fairly common cylindrical coordinate form.  Indeed, if I'd correctly understood the problem I was really trying to solve, I would have stated in the title that it was in cylindrical coordinates, as I did in this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414678/cylindrical-coordinate-convolution-between-dirac-deltas-for-a-plane-and-sphere

Comment: Don't understand, what you mean: Here we have a onedimensional integration along tau with scalar argument inside DiracDelta I think.

Comment: I changed the question to make your answer not mislead those of us who have more than 1 dimension to deal with.  So your answer is ok without the caveat now.  Although You might consider changing the formula in your answer to match:  `Sqrt[1+tau^2] == 0`